# Cassandra Commitlog taking more space on disk

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, nodetool

The commitlog in Cassandra is taking more space.

Can we clear it using `nodetool flush`?

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly attempt to force memtables to be flushed to disk but I doubt it will work.

When certain thresholds are reached, Cassandra does the flushing automatically but I suspect there's something wrong on the node so the commitlog just keeps getting bigger.

One common cause for flushes to not work is when the file permissions are wrong. For example, if you accidentally start Cassandra as the `root` user, new files are owned by `root` so the default Cassandra user no longer has the ability to do operations as memtable flushes and compaction.

Check the permissions and ownership on both (a) the files in the `commitlog/` directory, AND (b) the parent directories to make sure that the Cassandra user has access. Cheers!

Comment: We have 5 nodes with the same configuration, among them only on one node the commit log takes more space.

Comment: Can I run flush from the DataStax ops center? Will that work?

Comment: OpsCenter doesn't do any magic -- it runs the same code as `nodetool flush` to flush memtables. You need to investigate the underlying issue of why Cassandra can't perform flushes as normal. Cheers!

Comment: Mistakenly the /var/lib/datastax-agent/tmp was deleted and recreated with root user, from that time commit log was not deleted, I have changed the user back to cassandra.

Comment: Can I delete the old commit log? are anything need to be done here